# output tail command to mail

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am trying to get updates to /var/log/apache2/access.log and pass them to grep for certain criteria.  If there is a match, I want to send the hit my the mail command.  As a test, I am just trying to load "spacer.gif" in my web root.  The grep search searches for access log entries with "spacer.gif" in them:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep spacer.gif
```

This works and I see the log entries containing "spacer.gif" but no others.

I then tried:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep spacer.gif | mail -s 'Log Entry found' me@mydomain.com
```

I never get an email with the above.  I can confirm that

```
echo "this is test output" | mail -s 'this is a test' me@mydomain.com
```

does go through correctly.

Sorry, not very good with linux, obviously.  I'm on Ubuntu 20.X

I have seen similar questions on StackOverflow but these aren't working either.  Thanks for any help?

Comment: also, for example, I have tried "tail -f  /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep spacer.gif && mail -s 'Log Entry found' me@mydomain.com"  and can see the successful result on screen in stdout but, again, no result.

Answer (score 2):

Your `tail` command never terminates (due to `-f`). Therefore the input to `mail` nevers closes. Therefore `mail` does not know when it is OK to send the mail.

If you would kill the `tail` command, `mail` should complete its work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

`tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep spacer.gif > /tmp/access.out;mail -s "Access Log"  email@tester.com < /tmp/access.out`

Comment: This is interesting:  in trying this I note that "tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep spacer.gif > accesses.txt" never writes anything into the accesses.txt file.  However just running "tail -f /var/log/apache2/accesses.log | grep spacer.gif" does write the grep hits to the screen.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: this has something to do with the way "tail -f" works.   Just doing "tail /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep spacer.gif > text.txt" works but using the "-f" will never write to the file as far as I can tell.

Comment: Maybe something like this could work?? ` watch -d "cat /var/log/httpd/access.log|grep spacer.gif" > /tmp/test.out`

Comment: That will give me duplicate hits everytime watch runs.  Thats why I thought tail -f would be perfect. Additionally I'll get a duplicate email every 2 seconds (or whatever).  I think the issue is that when you issue the "tail -f" command, nothing happens because there is no update, but the mail command is trying to send and since there isn't an update yet, nothing happens.  I had thought that each time tail -f updates, it would also issue the mail command.  Maybe I need to output to a file with the tee command and monitor that file somehow?